# Aura, Aurum, Aurora & *h₂ews-

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european, latin

Good morning,

I am a scholar from a different field, trying to gain insight into the etymological connection between aura and aurum (air and gold). How do they relate?

I have found a connection through *h₂ews- (dawn, east), but I am not sure if I can go so far as to conclude that both terms derive from it, although wictionary does.

Michiel de Vaan (Brill Dictionary of Latin Etymology) seems more hesitant.

Any opinions? Thanks a lot in advance!

P.S. Bonus question: Whats's with auris, ear? Same root as well? Thanks! :-)

Comment: Why not asking it in the Latin StackExchange?

Comment: @Quidam. We are here and we are there. But who is down-voting this excellent question?

Comment: I don't know, it has been flagged by someone for closing it, probably to move it on the Latin SE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Latin aura is a loan from Greek αὔρα, for which the original meaning (still in Homer) is “morning mist”. In this case the connection with the Latin aurora “dawn” and aurum *glow > “gold”  is not difficult semantically, all deriving from an IE root *h₂ews-. On the other hand, auris “ear” is generally assumed to derive from a different IE homonym *h₂ews-. Is that satisfactory? I have my doubts.

Comment: This raises an interesting issue about the prevalence of homonyms/phones.

Comment: @BertBarrois. Yes, exactly.

Comment: Thank you! That's really helpful. So to break it down:

(1.) I can see clearly, how aura derives from αὔρα, which comes from *h₂ews-
(2.) I understand, that aura and aurora are evidently connected and both stem from *h₂ews- 

But I am still unsure about aurum. Mainly because *h₂ews- is not listed as a reference in the Latin Etymologic Dictionary. Or did I read it wrongly? 

Thanks again!

Comment: @sachaq. de Vaan derives aurum from *h₂e-h₂us-o-, with *h₂us- (zero-grade of *h₂ews-) and reduplication. Others have given slightly different explanations.

Comment: @fdb Ah, perfect! Know it makes sense! So if I quote the lemmata aurum and aurora in de Vries (and aura from an Ancient Greek etymological dictionary, I would have sufficient proof for the etymology, right? Or is there a better or more common source I should cite?

Comment: I am not sure that anything in linguistics is a sufficient proof. Linguistics is not an exact science.

Comment: Thanks though, for connecting the dots ;-)